# R Plotly - Format Currency

Tags: r, formatting, plotly

For a shiny app, I would like to plot a pie chart using plotly. The data consists of prices in the hundred thousands. In the chart I want to print the labels and values. Since I am from Germany, I would like the prices to be in € and the thousand separators to be dots.

I managed to print the labels and to format the prices as a currency using `texttemplate` as shown below:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(diamonds, labels = ~cut, values = ~price, type = 'pie',
        texttemplate = "%{label} <br> %{value:$,}")
```

However, I fail to change the currency to € and the separators to dots. I believe that in JAVA this can be achieved by setting the location. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in R.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the unicode `\U20AC` of the euro sign like this:

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(diamonds, labels = ~cut, values = ~price, type = 'pie',
        texttemplate = "%{label} <br> \U20AC%{value:,}")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To change separator to dots you can use `layout` with `separators` like this:

```r
library(plotly)
plot_ly(diamonds, labels = ~cut, values = ~price, type = 'pie',
        texttemplate = "%{label} <br> \U20AC%{value:,}") %>%
  layout(separators = ",.")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know a way to replace the commas with dots? E.g.: 63.221.498€

Comment: Hi @BenediktFranz, No problem, glad it helped! Could you please try replace , with . in the code above?

Comment: Hi Quinten, unfortunately, that doesn't work since the "," indicates that the number should be formated with separators between thousands. The default setting uses a ",". I don't know how to change this default option.

Comment: @BenediktFranz, Please see updated answer using `layout`.